# How to use optimize an e-commerce site for both .com and .co.uk?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, geotargeting, cctld

I had worked almost three months on a .com domain site and I am getting pretty good results on google.com, however, my ranking on google.co.uk is not that good so I have decided to buy an equivalent .co.uk domain.

My site is an e-commerce site and I am hoping to perform well for the U.S. and the U.K.

What are the best options to persue given my scenario to ensure that my site/site(s) performs both in the U.S. and U.K.?

Comment: What is your site? Is it an e-commerce site? Are you selling globally? Are you concerned that yo are not reaching customers effectively in the UK?

Comment: its a simple product website..im located in UK and I want to sell my products in US and UK.

Comment: should i apply redirection on my myexample.co.uk to myexample.com? will it be beneficial in terms of SEO

Answer (score 1):

Most of time, Google employee like matt cutts and John Muller said, use Different country level domain like example.com or example.co.uk or example.de when possible, and secondly option is sub-domain(like uk.example.com) and third option is sub directory(like example.com/uk/).

The main reason it that, Because Search engine spider understand it, you want to target this location, so most of time, they will display country related domain in search result.

For example,

If you search Google analytics from India, then you will get www.google.co.in/analytics in search result. If you search from UK, then you will get .co.uk result. But the page is same, it is even in same lanagage, but they just target to different location, which you can set in [Google Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en).

Similarly, Godaddy also provide same service on different location, but their price value is different, and hence Google is smart enough to don't consider as duplicate webpages.

So, just create .co.uk  domain for your website, change product currency from Dollar to Pound(I think they use pound), so Google understand this is not duplicate pages, also set target location in Google Webmaster Tools.

Please do not redirect .co.uk domain to .com site, it does not help in SEO anyway. Just like User redirect, Googlebot will do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the same exact site on your `.com` and our `.co.uk`   The `.co.uk` will automatically get targeted to the United Kingdom and enjoy good rankings there based on the top level domain name.

If you are not able to buy the `.co.uk` domain, you could also put the same site on a `uk.` subdomain and target it to the UK by adding it to Google Search Console and using the site country targeting feature.

Once you have the same site on two domains, it is probably worth your while to tweak it a bit:

- Adopt UK spellings and phrases where appropriate.
- Change pricing to the British Pound.
- Put in appropriate shipping options (for ecommerce sites.)
- Use local contact and support info if you have it.